# Can I deploy a Rails App directly onto my companies website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I have originally been hosting my apps on Heroku, however this is not an acceptable deployment method in my current environment. We have personal information in our applications that deploying to Heroku and setting up DNS forwarding is not acceptable. Regardless of how 'secure' or 'reliable' anyone may think it is, it is just not acceptable in my case.

Our host is siteturn.com, integrated with Plesk 10.4.4. If I SSH onto our websites server as admin and type

```
ruby -v
```

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux].

```
rails -v
```

Rails 2.3.5

It appears Ruby and Rails are already installed (Older versions than I require, as I need ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2) If I'm not mistaken it seems like my host 'supports' rails (why else would it already have it installed :P).

How should I go about deploying my application directly onto my companies website?

Comment: Ask your webhost to upgrade their rails to 3.2 with ruby 1.9.3. If they won't do that, then you cannot use them. simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is an awesome service but the ease of deploying to Heroku has given you a skewed view of what is involved in hosting your own rails website. Heroku has shielded you from a lot of the hard parts.

For example, just because ruby and rails is installed does not necessarily mean you can host a production rails website. You'll need a rails specific web server (for example nginx and passenger, unicorn, etc). You also need a database (MySQL or Postgres) assuming your web app uses one. Also, as you said you need to upgrade the versions of ruby and rails.

That's just to get the server setup. After that you can get to the deployment part. [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) seems to be the most popular choice right now.

Take a look at this [railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) on deploying to a virtual private server for a very good overview of what is involved. It also briefly goes into Capistrano as well. It's not a free episode but I feel it's definitly worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

Pick up a copy of Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition and read what it says about deployment.  That should get you started.  There's more info required than can be put in a SO answer.

Comment: The short version is: Yes, of course you can deploy to your own server, provided you can get it set up properly. The long version, as nbsp says, is at least a chapter of a book, possibly an entire book, depending on your preferred level of detail (if you're as concerned with security as you say, it's probably the latter)

Comment: OK Well I guess I'm starting to see that. Rails seems so easy until its time to deploy. I will attempt to do these things on my own and when I run into questions I will ask them individually. Thank you and votes up.

Comment: @MoB Rails is easy to deploy when you know how. Be sure to use some decent tools like Capistrano (which deploys from a git repo). On the server side, you should be familiar with installing Ruby (via RVM or whatnot), and the dependencies. If the server supports it already, it couldn't be easier to deploy than with Capistrano.